# Swift4- insert a string of text into textview field in another view/class

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift4, data-transfer

I am recreating a simple app that is a paramedic case logger, effectively it is a bunch of buttons or textfields that get their .text value time stamped and pasted into a UItextView field to create a chronological list of action to refer back to when a paramedic writes up their patient notes.

I have created a tab bar controlled app using the Xcode template.
I have created the UIbuttons and UItextfields that create and paste the string into a test UItextview on the same field.
I have created a func that creates the time stamp string

I run into trouble getting the same string to show on the UItextview on the 2nd view.

RESEARCH
As I am only new to this I have read lots of posts on here with user defaults, segues, delegates/protocols and cannot seem to effectively implement these in my specific circumstance (still not super sure I understand those enough yet to do it).

I have got the point that I have saved the string into a user.default value and then I can use that value in the 2nd view with a func to insert the text and clear the user.default value but I cannot seem to get the function to run from the first view? (get the encounter nil value error).

I feel like this should be a pretty simple process, so not getting it to function is very frustrating...

QUESTION
So I was hoping someone might be able to demo the simple way to take a UItextField.text input from FirstViewController and then when a UIbutton is pressed on FirstViewController pass the string to SecondViewController and insert it into a UITextView field (I don't want to display the 2nd view).

From this demo I'm hoping I can reverse engineer a solution into my code as a learning opportunity without just having my exact code handed to me on a silver platter.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// View OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var customNoteField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var reportTextViewFieldTemp: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastEntryTV: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var caseIDTF: UITextField!



// Class VARIABLES

    let timeButtonArray = ["blank0", "Call Received1", "Dispatched2", "Enroute3", "On Scene4", "At Patient5", "Depart Scene6", "At Hospital7", "Available8",]




    // VIEW DID LOAD STUFF
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        self.customNoteField.delegate = self

    }

    //TIMING BUTTON PRESSED
    @IBAction func timeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //GATHER DATA
        let timingButtonInput = timeButtonArray[sender.tag]
        let DTGstamp = dateTimeStamp()

        //FORM STRING
        let buttonData = ("\(DTGstamp) \(timingButtonInput) \n")

        //SEND buttonDATA TO ReportViewController
        /*??? The part I need help with*/

    }

    //CUSTOM ENTRY UITextfield PRESSED
    @IBAction func customNoteDone(_ sender: Any) {

        //GATHER DATA
        let DTGstamp = dateTimeStamp()
        let customNote = customNoteField.text

        //FORM STRING
        let customData = ("\(DTGstamp) \(customNote) \n")

        //TEST FOR EMPTY TEXT
        if customNote != "" {

            //SEND customDATA TO ReportViewController
            /*??? The part I need help with*/

        }

//FUNCTION TO GENERATE DATE,TIME GROUP AS CONSTANT
    func dateTimeStamp() -> String {
        var date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddLLLyy HH:mm:ss"
        print (dateFormatter.string(from: date))
        return (dateFormatter.string(from: date))

    }

}




//
//  ReportViewController.swift
//  EMS Case Logger
//
//  Created by Allan Ravenscroft on 3/3/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Allan Ravenscroft. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ReportViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var reportTextViewField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reportEmailButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reportEditButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reportClearButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        reportEditButton.layer.cornerRadius = reportEditButton.frame.height / 2
        reportEmailButton.layer.cornerRadius = reportEmailButton.frame.height / 2
        reportClearButton.layer.cornerRadius = reportClearButton.frame.height / 2
    }


    //Actions when the clear button is pressed
    @IBAction func clearButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        reportTextViewField.text = ""
    }


    //Actions when the edit button is pressed
    @IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }


    //Actions when the email button is pressed
    @IBAction func emailButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        showMailComposer(bodytext: reportTextViewField.text)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use singleton.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-Singleton-class-in-Swift. I think that is used for Global variable, That is same static variable in JAVA

Comment: You don't want to try updating the second view directly. In fact the first view shouldn't even know the second view exists. You should investigate a more structured approach to managing your views and data and changes therein. The most basic model and one which can be adapted to your scenario is MVC. A tutorial from the always excellent Ray Wenderlich here: [https://www.raywenderlich.com/1073-model-view-controller-mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach]. Try working through the tutorial carefully. In your case the two views can share the same model

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a demo, but maybe can help you

Make a new NSObject file

inside the class put a new variable

```
import UIKit

class test: NSObject {
    var a:String = ""
}
```

at your ViewController declare a new var referencing the class

```
let testVar = test()
```

in your customNote checker

```
test.a = customNote
```

then at your 2nd ViewController, do the same thing

```
let testVar = test()
testVar.a //this is your customNote String
```

hope this helps